Function in flask app can't find variable, but online flask debugger can
I've been working on a python web development course, and my course wants me to make a website that lists some cafés in London. I'm trying to code the functionality to add a café, but when I run the flask app, it says it can't find a variable that I defined using exec(). But when I log into the debugger that flask sets up and run print(<name-of-variable-I-defined-using-exec), it returns the value of the variable. Here is my code:
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap5
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, URLField, TimeField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, URL
import csv

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '8BYkEfBA6O6donzWlSihBXox7C0sKR6b'
Bootstrap5(app)

# @app.route("/cafe")
# def cafe_page():
#     index = 0
#     with open("cafe-data.csv") as file:
#         coffee_shops = file.readlines()
#
#     coffee_shops.pop(0)
#
#     for shop in coffee_shops:
#         coffee_shops[index] = shop.replace("\n", "")
#
#     return render_template("cafes.html", coffe_shops=coffee_shops)

class CafeForm(FlaskForm):
    cafe_name = StringField('Cafe name', validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")])
    location = URLField(label="Location", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required"), URL()])
    open_time = TimeField(label="Open time", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")])
    close_time = TimeField(label="Close time", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")])
    coffee = SelectField(label="Coffee rating", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")], choices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    wifi = SelectField(label="WiFi rating", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")], choices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
    power = SelectField(label="Power rating", validators=[DataRequired(message="This field is required")], choices=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

# Exercise:
# add: Location URL, open time, closing time, coffee rating, wifi rating, power outlet rating fields
# make coffee/wifi/power a select element with choice of 0 to 5.
#e.g. You could use emojis ☕️//✘/
# make all fields required except submit
# use a validator to check that the URL field has a URL entered.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

def replace_characters(form_item, character):
    form_data_list = []
    range_index = exec(f"test = CafeForm().{form_item}.data")
    print(test)
    for character in range(1, int(test)):
        form_data_list.append(character)

    for character in form_data_list:
        print(character)
        form_data_list[character - 1] = "☕"

# all Flask routes below
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add_cafe():
    form = CafeForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print("True")
        with open("cafe-data.csv", encoding="utf-8", mode="a") as csv_file:

            replace_characters("coffee", "☕")

            csv_file.write(f"{form.cafe_name.data},{form.location.data},{form.open_time.data},{form.close_time.data},{form.coffee.data},{form.wifi.data},{form.power.data}")
    # Exercise:
    # Make the form write a new row into cafe-data.csv
    # with   if form.validate_on_submit()
    return render_template('add.html', form=form)


@app.route('/cafes')
def cafes():
    with open('cafe-data.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
        csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        list_of_rows = [row for row in csv_data]

        list_of_rows.pop(0)

    return render_template('cafes.html', cafes=list_of_rows)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)


Any help would be much appreciated.

In my opinion it would be more useful to use getattr() than exec(). Unfortunately it is not clear what you intend to do with the function replace_characters(). Can you describe in words what it should output/do?

test = CafeForm().getattr(form_item).data

Why doesn't replace_characters() use the character parameter?

You don't need either of the for loops. The whole thing could be range_index = CafeForm().getattr(form_item).data followed bu return [character] * range_index
